# Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my render method I have component

```
<DatePicker selected={this.state.startDate} onChange={this.handleChange()}/>
```

handleChange is following

```
handleChange: function (e) {
  var that = this;
  console.log(e.target.value)
  return function () {
    that.setState({
      startDate: e.target.value
    });
  }
},
```

By when I try to load page with this component, I get error

> Cannot read property 'target' of undefined

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The problem is that you are invoking the function  in this line:

```
onChange={this.handleChange()}
```

All you have to do is simply pass the function as a value to onChange without invoking it.

```
onChange={this.handleChange}
```

When you use parenthesis you'd be invoking a function/method instead of binding it with an event handler. Compare the following two examples:

```
//invokes handleChange() and stores what the function returns in testA.
const testA = this.handleChange()
```

vs

```
//stores the function itself in testB. testB be is now a function and may be invoked - testB();
const testB = this.handleChange
```

Comment: Great answer! Helped me out as well.

Comment: what about if you want to pass a parameter

Comment: like so onMouseOver={(event) => { this.moveBall(event) }}

Comment: @MaxwellLynn if you want to pass an argument - onMouseOver={ (e) => this.moveBall(e) }

Answer (score 4):

If you are passing event using an arrow function, you should try the following:

```
onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are executing function rather than passing it as a prop.

You need to change this,

```
 onChange={this.handleChange()}
```

with this,

```
 onChange={this.handleChange}
```

Comment: Now I get Warning: bind(): You are binding a component method to the component. React does this for you automatically in a high-performance way, so you can safely remove this call. See ClientOrderList and when I trigger onChange - TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

Comment: He does not need to bind. Bind works on functions, not methods. Check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this

```
<DatePicker selected={this.state.startDate} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
```

It will pass the event param of the function automatically. The rest of your code is okay.

Answer (score 0):

Changing this `onChange={this.handleChange}` to this `onChange={() => this.handleChange()}` may also help if all the suggestions above don't work.

Comment: This is not a good idea. Setting up an anonymous function hinders React's performance. You should always use `this.handleChange` and never setup an anonymous function inside of the render function unless you have to (passing args for example)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it like this

```
function handleChange(event) {
    const value =  event.taget.value;
}

<input onChange={handleChange} />

not this

<input onChange={handleChange()} />
```

Comment: Welcome, thank you for your time in answering this question. Can you please give more details about your solution? For example, why is your solution better than the highly upvoted accepted answer? Also, the question was asked and answered 3 years ago. Be sure to look at the date of the original question when answering.