# ReactJS: Stop input from automatically being submitted

Tags: reactjs

After selecting a date from the dropdown calendar and setting the time the value is automatically submitted.  However, I want use the submit button to submit the value.  From research I thought, 'event.preventDefault();', statement was suppose to prevent such a thing.  Also, is the value stored in inputValue?  If it is, how do I access that value from outside the calendar class?

So, again to be clear, I want to submit the value using the submit button.

```
class Calendar extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                inputValue: '',

            }
            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
            this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        }


        handleChange(event) {
            this.state.inputValue = event.target.valueAsNumber;
            console.log('Form value: ' + this.state.inputValue);
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        handleSubmit(event) {

            this.state.inputValue = event.target.valueAsNumber;
            console.log('Form value: ' + this.state.inputValue);
            event.preventDefault();
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div className="Calendar">
                    <form onSubmit="return handleSubmit();">
                        <label>Date/Time</label>
                        <input type="datetime-local" value={this.state.inputValue} onChange={this.handleChange()} />
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </form>
                </div>
                 //{this.render(){return (<UserList />)};
            );
        }
    };
    export default Calendar;
```

Comment: If you want to access the value outside the class, consider move the value to the parent state and let the parent pass the value to which component who needs it

Comment: @EdwinHarly I am very new to ReactJS (started a few days ago) so can you offer a bit more explanation.  Also, if you can add an example that would be even better.

Comment: Post a new question about it as it is OOT

Comment: On a second thought, about state management and stuff, I think it's a fairly common question, so I guess it isn't very hard to search for

Comment: What is an OOT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried creating a test app using the code provided by you and therefore analyze the code, I found many issues in the code.

I have written another version of the code, removing the bugs or mistakes. Find the code at **[JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/mukherjeeronit/n5u2wwjg/112002/)** and I am also pasting the basic ***code(Component Class)*** here too.

```
class Calendar extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      inputValue: '',
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }


  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        "inputValue":event.target.value
    });
  }

    handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log("Input Value:",this.state.inputValue)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Calendar">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>Date/Time</label>
          <input type="datetime-local" 
                 value={this.state.inputValue}   
                 onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
      //{this.render(){return (<UserList />)};
    );
  }
};
```

1. The issues which were there in the code are the following:-
   `this.state.inputValue = event.target.valueAsNumber` setting the
   state directly is not allowed, therefore I converted the code with
   `this.setState`
2. input type `datetime-local` expects the value format to be like
   "1990-11-02T12:59" so replaced it with `event.target.value`
3. `onChange="return handleChange()"` is not the prescribed way to call
   function of the component class inside render, using **()** with
   function name directly call the function on the page load which we
   don't want, therefore replaced the code with
   `onChange={this.handleChange}`
4. `onSubmit="return handleSubmit();"` will call the handleSubmit
   function as soon as the component loads and this is not the
   prescribed way too, therefore replaced the code with
   `onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}`
5. in `handleSubmit` function we don't need to set the state again as
   it's already updated whenever the value of the input changes using
   the `handleChange` function. So here if you want then you can call
   any function of the parent using the
   `this.props.parentFunc(this.state.inputValue)` and use the input
   value further.

*For any further query feel free to comment or email me at connect.ronit@mail.com*

Comment: this worked.  And thanks for the explanation; greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would also like to be able to input the seconds.  Currently I can only input HH:mm.  Do I need to ask another question for that?

Comment: I made the following changes to handleSubmit()  
`handleSubmit(event) {
        // this.setState({
        //     inputValue: event.target.valueAsNumber
        // });
        this.state.inputValue = event.target.valueAsNumber;
        console.log("Input Value:", event.target.valueAsNumber)
        event.preventDefault();
    }`   and received the following error: Input Value: undefined

Comment: @N6DYN I guess you are trying to add those bugs again into the code by using this.state.inputValue, it's not prescribed and not allowed. 

Thanks for asking, glad to help you over skype too:- connect.ronit

Comment: I am trying to have the input converted to Unix time (Epoch).

Comment: @N6DYN Sad to see you unaccepted the answer. Secondly, if you wish to have value in Unix Time convert it in submit function

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that the following line causes `handleSubmit()` to execute immediately, when the component is rendered:

```
<form onSubmit="return handleSubmit();">
```

In order words, when your component renders, it is calling `handleSubmit()` when "binding a handler" to the forms `onSubmit` event.

If you revise your code as follows, this will prevent the form from being submit/executed automatically while achieving the desired form submit behaviour:

```
<form onSubmit={(event) => this.handleSubmit(event)}>
```

Comment: After I made your change I received the following error:    

TypeError: Cannot read property 'target' of undefined  
  19 |   
  20 | handleChange(event) {  
> 21 |     this.state.inputValue = event.target.valueAsNumber;  
  22 |     console.log('Form value: ' + this.state.inputValue);  
  23 |     event.preventDefault();  
  24 | }

Comment: Used this to fixed error above, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389220/cannot-read-property-target-of-undefined

But after I reloaded the form and filled out the input field the value was automatically sent with after hitting 'p' for PM. I have been on this all day troubleshooting and eveything I have found said onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} and event.preventDefault(); in the handleSubmit(event) function should work but it is not.

Comment: Still acting the same.  Also received the following warning:    
Warning: Expected `onSubmit` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type.

Comment: Sorry about that, answering from phone, see corrections. The {..} need to be used in place of the ".."

Comment: Made the following change and same behavior:  <form onSubmit={(event) => this.handleSubmit(event)}>

Comment: Yes that's correct, see the updated answer - hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the problem,the form was submitting automatically because you gave the value attribute as the state.inputValue, which is not required. The onChange attribute is also not required.Please try the following code

```
class Calender extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputValue: ""
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ inputValue: document.getElementById("time").value });
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.inputValue);
    return (
      <div className="Calendar">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>Date/Time</label>
          <input type="datetime-local" id="time" />
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      </div>
      //{this.render(){return (<UserList />)};
    );
  }
}
```

Also please not that you may not get the state value immediately after it is set.The working example is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/3q3y7v69p6)

Comment: @N6DYN Here is the working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/3q3y7v69p6)

Comment: Made the changes to both handleSubmit and handleChange and the application is still acting the same.

Comment: @N6DYN Is it showing the error or do not getting the expected functionality

Comment: I tried your example and it is acting the same as mine. The value is being submitted as soon as the input box is filled.  I would like to submit the value only after pressing the submit button.

Comment: @N6DYN I have made some more edits.Please do check and update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176957/discussion-between-n6dyn-and-harikrishnan).