# Cannot read property 'target' of undefined - HTML buttons

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, typeerror

Why am I getting this error?

```
Cannot read property 'target' of undefined
  at btn
```

I declare `btn()` in my html file. I have multiples buttons in the html invoking `btn()`.

```
function btn(event){        
  var theTarget = event.target;
  alert(theTarget.tagName);
}
```

Comment: How you are calling on function, please mention it. It should be on any **event**, e.g. **onclick**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot read property 'target' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46389220/cannot-read-property-target-of-undefined)

Comment: would help if you also show how you're calling btn in your markup

Comment: Are you binding this function, or calling it directly in the HTML?

Comment: Do you pass any argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options for how to do this, and each behaves differently.

**Option 1**
Set `onclick="btn(this)"` on the button. This *always* passes the button itself as the argument. The other options pass an event as opposed to the element itself.

```js
function btn(elem) {
  var theTarget = elem;
  console.log(theTarget.id);
}
```

```html
<p>
  Option 1:
  <button id="the-button" onclick="btn(this)">
    btn(this)
    <span id="the-span" style="border: 1px solid red">This is a span</span>
  </button>
</p>
```

**Option 2**
Set `onclick="btn(event)"` on the button. This passes the event, and `event.target` will be element that is clicked. For example, an event referencing a `span` inside the button would be passed if it was clicked.

```js
function btn(evt) {
  var theTarget = evt.target;
  console.log(theTarget.id);
}
```

```html
<p>
  Option 2:
  <button id="the-button" onclick="btn(event)">
    btn(event)
    <span id="the-span" style="border: 1px solid red">This is a span</span>
  </button>
</p>
</p>
```

**Option 3**
Set an `id` attribute for the button. Then bind an event handler to the button with JavaScript. This behaves like option 2 with respect to the way child elements are referenced by the event.

```js
function btn(evt) {
  var theTarget = evt.target;
  console.log(theTarget.id);
}

document.getElementById('the-button').onclick = btn;
```

```html
<p>
  Option 3:
  <button id="the-button">
    binding
    <span id="the-span" style="border: 1px solid red">This is a span</span>
  </button>
</p>
```

Here is a snippet with all three options in one program:

```js
function btn(evt) {
  var theTarget = evt.target || evt;
  console.log(theTarget.id);
}

document.getElementById('third-button').onclick = btn;
```

```html
<p>
  Option 1:
  <button id="first-button" onclick="btn(this)">
    btn(this)
    <span id="first-button-SPAN" style="border: 1px solid red">This is a span</span>
  </button>
</p>

<p>
  Option 2:
  <button id="second-button" onclick="btn(event)">
    btn(event)
    <span id="second-button-SPAN" style="border: 1px solid red">This is a span</span>
  </button>
</p>

<p>
  Option 3:
  <button id="third-button">
    binding
    <span id="third-button-SPAN" style="border: 1px solid red">This is a span</span>
  </button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggests that the `event` parameter has not been set (i.e. is undefined) when the `btn(...)` method was called.

You should verify that `event` is set whenever the code tries to use that method.

It might also be safer to not use `event` as the parameter name in your function - this might cause problems (i.e. it's [apparently a global variable in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1510106/1751331)). Try changing it to `myEvent`?

Answer (score 0):

Note: When we call the function from the HTML we get the button directly i.e. the `target`.

With binding we get `event`

```js
function btn(event){        
    var theTarget = event.target || event;
    alert(theTarget.tagName);
}

document.querySelector('#boundEvent').onclick = btn;
```

```html
<!-- In this way we are passing the button directly. -->
<button onclick="btn(this);">Direct call</button>
<!-- When we bind in our code (Best way) we will get an event object. --> 
<button id="boundEvent">Bound Event</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default function takes arguments values as **undefined** in JavaScript so I wish you have forgotten to pass **event** to handler function i.e. to **btn()**.

> A best simple example to understand this concept would be 
>   https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_target.asp

So instead of calling like `onclick=btn()` or `onclick=btn(this)`, prefer  `onclick=btn(event)`, the correct one otherwise `undefined` will be taken as default value.